# Python 3 Struct unpack int and bytearray

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, arrays

I am using Python 3, receiving a bytearray through mqtt. The 1st 4 bytes is integer that is unix timestamp. The rest of the data is bytes that I am going to convert into base 64 string. How do I separate the integer and the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just slice the array:

```
timestamp, base64_data = ba_object[:4], ba_object[4:]
```

The timestamp could be extracted with the [`int.from_bytes()` class method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes), while the base64-encoded data can be handled with `base64.b64decode()`:

```
import base64

timestamp = int.from_bytes(ba_object[:4], byteorder='big')
data = base64.b64decode(ba_object[4:])
```

Comment: if I do  messagebyte = bytearray(msg.payload)
messagebyte is ba_object?

Comment: @user903772: yes, `ba_object` stands for *byte array object* here; use whatever name you have.

Comment: I don't need to use struct?

Comment: For base64 data and one integer I'd not use struct.

Comment: shouldn't data be: data = base64.b64decode(ba_object[5:])?

Comment: @user903772: only if you need to skip the first 5 bytes.

Comment: timestamp = int.from_bytes(messagebyte[:4], byte_order='big')
typeError: Required argument 'byteorder' (pos 2) not found

Comment: @user903772: I typo-ed, remove the underscore.